# An unadorned jQuery(identifier).datepicker() is failing. What of the basics have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I run an installation <script> of jquery-1.8.0-min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js; the latter was set to include everything, and in particular datepicker.

After that I have JavaScript that runs:

```
jQuery(function()
    {
    jQuery('#event_date').datepicker();
    });
```

In Chrome this gives the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker' logistic.js:777
(anonymous function) logistic.js:777
p.Callbacks.k jquery.js:2
p.Callbacks.l.fireWith jquery.js:2
p.extend.ready jquery.js:2
D
```

When I check it in the browser nothing interesting happens when I click in the text field that should have been replaced by a datepicker; it just gets focus.

Any ideas what is (not?) going on here?

Comment: what order are you importing the scripts?

Comment: What is `logistic.js`? Please show the actual `<script>` elements that include the external JS files.

Comment: Are you loading some other Javascript library that use the `$` variable like jQuery does? Make sure you use `jQuery.noconflict()`.

Comment: I forgot that later down the page was a [not H5BP] boilerplate jQuery include further down, so I was overwriting the UI script.